# Como añadir un icono en una cadena de texto js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Mi consulta es quiero añadir un icono animado en el texto `procesando...` pero no se como llamar a esa etiqueta dentro de la hoja .js

Necesito que la variable `$spiner` alamacene al icono animado y lo muestre en la cadena de texto `'$spiner + procesando...'` de js.

https://prnt.sc/qg2XgqvjAG1O

```js
var $spiner = '<i class="bx bx-loader-circle bx-spin" ></i>';
$('#Enviar').val($spiner+'Procesando...');
```

Comment: Por favor, muestra tu código como que has intentado hacerlo, también es recomendable que lo hagas con formato texto y no siendo una imagen .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tendrías que usar [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) en lugar de `.val()`

#### Ejemplo:

```js
$('#Enviar').on('click', function() {
  var $spiner = '<i class="bx bx-loader-circle bx-spin" ></i>';
  $('#Enviar').html($spiner + 'Procesando...');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<button id="Enviar">Enviar</button>
```

Comment: Excelente @Marcos, te agradezco.